# How does this C code translate to MIPS instruction?

Tags: c, mips

I'm studying mips coding and have a solution to a given problem and I'm working to understand it and have defined each line to the best my knowledge, but I'm not picking up on a couple of lines on how they work mainly the last line with fib(n-1) + fib(n-2) how is that being returned? I see that after beq fails, and bne fails t1 is turned to 0 and exit is reached the value from t1 is stored to v0 for results/expressions and our (n) is reloaded before being deleted from the stack but I'm not quite seeing the fib(n-1) + fib(n-2) ? Help? Thank you!

```
C code:
int fib(int n){
if (n==0)
return 0;
else if (n == 1)
return 1;
else
fib(n-1) + fib(n–2);
```

NEW** answer/ transliteration I worked on

#

```
  #fib function
  loop:
  addi $sp, $sp, -4                 #creating item on stack -> int n given caller value
  sw $ra, 0($sp)                       #saving address to stack
  addi $t0, $zero, $zero               #temp 0 is given value of 0
  beq 0($sp), $t0, exit                #if equal return 0  (if (n == 0)
  addi $t1, $zero, 1                   #temp1 gets value of 1
  beq 0($sp), $t1, exit                #if equal return 0 (else if(n==0)
  lw $t2, 0($sp)                       #storing n to temp 2 
  sub $t2, $t2, 1                      #n - 1
  lw $t3, 0($sp)                       #storing n to temp 3
  sub $t3, $t3, 2 #n-2
  add $t4, $t2, $t3                    # (fib(n-1) + fib( n-1) 
  sw 0($sp), $s4                       #storing n's new value back to its original       location
  bne 0($sp), $zero, loop              #jump to loop function with new value of n
  exit: jr $ra                         #return value of register address to caller
```

//OLD***Partially correct answer but not correct transliteration for fibanocci
//---------------------------

```
compare:
addi $sp, $sp, –4 #add immediate adjusts stack for one more item
sw   $ra, 0($sp)  #saves return address on stack of our new item

add $s0, $a0, $0  #add, stores argument 0 + (0) to s0
add $s1, $a1, $0  #add, stores argument 0 + (0) to s1

jal sub           #jump and link to subtract

addi $t1, $0, 1   #add immediate, temp 1 = add 0 + 1
beq $v0, $0, exit #branch on equal, if value in 0 is equal to zero go to -> exit 
slt $t2, $0, $v0  #set less than, if 0 < value at 0  then temp2 equals 1 else 0
bne $t2, $0, exit #branch on not equal, if temp2 not equal to zero go to -> exit
addi $t1, $0, $0  #add immediate, temp1 = 0 + 0

exit:
add $v0, $t1, $0  #add value at 0 = t1 + 0
lw $ra, 0($sp)    #loads register address from stack 0()
addi $sp, $sp, 4  #add immediate, deletes stack pointer pops it off stack
jr $ra            #jump register, return to caller from return address

sub:
sub $v0, $a0, $a1 #subtract, value at 0 = argument 1 - argument 2
jr $ra            #jump register, return to caller from return address
```

//

Comment: Read the wikipage on [call stacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)

Comment: The best thing to do if you don't understand the code given is probably to step through it in a debugger to see how it is executing

Comment: I don't really get the question. You've posted a C function that's supposed to compute the n:th number in the fibonacci series, and then you've posted some assembly code for a function that does something else entirely. How is the assembly code snippet related to the question?

Comment: You're right on that the book gave the solution for the transliteration of this fibnocci function as this... and left me confused and after asking and studying more indeph I wrote the mips translation myself I will post it up

Comment: Does this code look more correct?

Answer (score 1):

Neither version will work as suggested. I haven't tested the below code; but something like this should work (no error check (assumes $a0 non-negative); lenient procedure frame convention):

```
        .text
fib:  addi $sp, $sp, -24
      sw $ra, 16($sp)
      sw $a0, 20(sp)         # recursive calls will overwrite original $a0
      sw $s0. 0($sp)         # holds fib(n-1)
      # end prologue

      slti $t0, $a0, 4      # fib(i) = i for i = 1, 2, 3; fib(0) = 0 by C code
      beq $t0, $zero, L1
      addi $v0, $a0, 0      # see prior comment (assumes $a0 non-negative integer)
      j exit

      # fib(n) = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
L1:   addi $a0, $a0, -1
      jal fib
      addi $s0, $v0, 0       # $s0 = fib(n-1)
      addi $a0, $a0, -1
      jal fib                # upon return, $v0 holds fib(n-2)
      add $v0, $v0, $s0

exit: # unwind stack and return
      lw $s0, 0($sp)
      lw $a0, 20($sp)
      lw $ra, 16($sp)
      addi $sp, $sp, 24
      jr $ra
```

Comment: fib(i) = i for i = 1, 2, 3; !! `f(2) = 1`, `f(3) = 2`